# New to makefiles - no clue how to make it work

Tags: c, makefile

When compiling my program, the makefile outputs this error:

cc sherpa.c -o -O2 -Wall

sherpa.c:4:10: fatal error: vte/vte.h: No such file or directory

was gonna post the code here but the formatting is weird so here's the github link https://github.com/amogus3016/sherpa

EDIT: code below

```
// Sherpa Terminal Emulator //
// This program is licensed under the GNU GPL 3.0, which provides absolutely NO WARRANTY //
__________________
|        |
| //         |
|  //        |
|   //       |
|  //        |
| //         |
|________________|
    
#include <vte/vte.h>

static void
child_ready(VteTerminal *terminal, GPid pid, GError *error, gpointer user_Data)
{
    if (!terminal) return;
    if (pid == -1) gtk_main_quit();
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *terminal;

    /* init gtk window and terminal */
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    terminal = vte_terminal_new();
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Sherpa");

    /* start new shell */
    gchar **envp = g_get_environ();
    gchar **command = (gchar *[]){g_strdup(g_environ_getenv(envp, "SHELL")), NULL };
    g_strfreev(envp);
    vte_terminal_spawn_async(VTE_TERMINAL(terminal),
        VTE_PTY_DEFAULT,
        NULL,   /* working dir */
        command,    /* command */
        NULL,   /* environment */
        0,  /* spawn flags */
        NULL, NULL, /* child setup */
        NULL,   /* child pid */
        -1, /* timeout */
        NULL,   /* cancellable */
        child_ready,    /* callback */
        NULL);  /* user_data */

    /* connect signals */
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
    g_signal_connect(terminal, "child-exited", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    /* combine widgets and run main loop */
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), terminal);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

and the makefile:

```
sherpa: sherpa.c
         $(CC) sherpa.c -o -O2 -Wall
         printf("Building executable [|]")
         printf("Building executable [/]")
         printf("Building executable [-]")
         printf("Building executable [\]")
         printf("Building executable [|]")
         mv ./sherpa /usr/bin
         printf("Installing [|]")
         printf("Installing [/]")
         printf("Installing [-]")
         printf("Installing [\]")
         printf("Installing [|]")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an [mcve].  Everything must be directly in the question as text, since links can break.

Comment: It looks like you don't have `vte/vte.h` in your include path.  How do you compile without the Makefile?  Probably something like `gcc -o -O2 -Wall -I/path/to/includes sherpa.c`.  Put `/path/to/includes` in the Makefile recipe.

Comment: gnu make allows you to put the `-I` option in `CPPFLAGS`, but sus only mandates `CFLAGS`.  You can probably just add `CPPFLAGS=-I/path` near the top of your Makefile.  But first you need to figure out the path where `vte.h` is installed.

Comment: OT: Why doesn't the option `-o` have a parameter? IIRC it needs a filename for the output file.

Comment: @StephenNewell added both the code and makefile

Comment: @WilliamPursell gcc -O2 -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags vte-2.91) sherpa.c -o sherpa $(pkg-config --libs vte-2.91)

Comment: @WilliamPursell How would I go about installing vte? sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: Is `pkg-config` working for you?  You could run `pkg-config` directly to see what flags it is using, or you can add the calls to `pkg-config` in your makefile.  Probably best to add it to `CPPFLAGS` with `CPPFLAGS=$$(pkg-config --cflags vte-2.9.1)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Not sure, `pkg-config` prints no output when I run `pkg-config sherpa.c`, I also tried adding that line to my makefile and it didn't work, also sorry if I sound stupid I just got into C lol

Comment: Try running `pkg-config --libs vte-2.91` and `pkg-config --cflags vte-2.91`, as shown in the command you are successfully using to compile.

Comment: @WilliamPursell appears to have worked

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should rely on the default rules that make uses.  In your case, since you are building an executable named `sherpa` from a file named `sherpa.c`, you can pretty much rely on the built-in rules for everything.  The only thing atypical you are doing is using `mv` to install the executable, and the more typical usage would be to put that in a separate rule.  In other words, your entire Makefile could simply be:

```
CFLAGS += $$(pkg-config --cflags vte-2.91)
LDFLAGS += $$(pkg-config --libs vte-2.91)
.PHONY: install all
all: sherpa
install: sherpa
         mv ./sherpa /usr/bin
```

If you don't include the `install` recipe (which, IMO, you should not.  Installing a package should have more infrastructure than merely copying the executable to /usr/bin), you can delete the last 4 lines of the file.  (This would require that the user type `make sherpa` instead of just `make`, so keeping `all: sherpa` is reasonable, but you don't need to specify the build command.)

By using `+=` when assigning CFLAGS and LDFLAGS, you allow the user to add flags at run time.  eg, you can invoke `CFLAGS='-g -O2' make` to build the executable with optimizations enabled.